# Why won't qml files load once I made them into a library?

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, qtquick2

My project looks like this:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── main.cpp
    └── radon
        ├── main.qml
        ├── qml.qrc
        ├── radon.cpp
        └── radon.h
```

The `src/CMakeList.txt` defines two targets, a library and an executable that links to the library.

```
# only relevant code shown
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
find_package(Qt5 5.15 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
add_library(RadonCore
        radon/radon.h
        radon/radon.cpp
        radon/qml.qrc
        )

target_link_libraries(RadonCore
        PUBLIC Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick)

add_executable(RadonApp
        main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(RadonApp
        PRIVATE RadonCore)
```

The library simply contains the entry point to my application, `main.cpp` merely calls the entry.

```cpp
// header
#ifndef RADON_RADON_H
#define RADON_RADON_H

namespace radon{
    int radon_entry(int argc, char* argv[]);
}

#endif //RADON_RADON_H
```

```cpp
// source
#include "radon.h"
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int radon::radon_entry(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // only relevant code shown
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    engine.load(url);

    return QGuiApplication::exec();
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "radon/radon.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return radon::radon_entry(argc, argv);
}
```

The idea of making the entry independent of `main()` is so that I can link the library to tests that have their own `main()`. However, under the configuration, qt complains about not able to find `main.qml`

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml: No such file or directory
```

If I provide a `main()` inside `radon.cpp` and built it as an executable, then it works fine. What gives?

The `qml.qrc` looks like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `RadonCore` is a static library. In Qt, if a static library uses resources, it must expand the `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` macro somewhere before first use. For more, see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-a-library). Note that the macro cannot be placed inside any namespaces (excluding global namespace). So the solution to this problem would so look like this:

1. extract `radon_entry` to the global namespace
2. place a macro call of `Q_INIT_RESOURCE(qml)` on the first line of `radon_entry`